# Is there any case wherein I would rather use XHTML over HTML5?

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm trying to find more information for XHTML, but all I found are arguments against it, or weighing it in comparison to HTML 4.x

Is there any reason one would still use XHTML or is it becoming a web relic?

Comment: Older browsers that don't support HTML5 is the main reason. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML_5%29 for details.

Comment: Over HTML 4.x? Or an older HTML version?

Comment: @Joren But "older browsers" also don't support XHTML. IE8 for instance can't handle XHTML files at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you need your HTML document to be valid XML, then use XHTML.

But since (X)HTML5 allows both HTML and XHTML code, then you can have XHTML5, with all the advantages of both XHTML and HTML5.

Comment: Depending on how you write the XHTML5, it won't have "all" the advantages. For example, documents served up with `application/xhtml+xml` won't recognise entity references such as `&shy;` and `&nbsp;`